# Самая простая база данных для использования внутри С++ приложения?

Tags: c++, sql, база-данных, boost

Пишу программу моделирования движения руки робота, выдвигаю и проверяю разные гипотезы, сталкнулся с проблемой: нужно где-то централизовано хранить точки траекторий. Обрабатывать точки нужно выборочно в зависимости от расстояния до цели, т.е. нужно иметь возможность выбора из хранилища по совокупности определённых условий. Начал писать с std::map и понял, что из неё вытащить точки, попадающие в регион по двум координатам (x, y) одновременно, не получится (получится, но бегать придётся дважды).

Выхода 3:

1. boost multi-index map
2. kd-tree с реализацией структур хранения самостоятельно
3. полноценная SQL DB

Что мне посоветуете выбрать?
Если 3 то - из множества всех БД с какой будет проще всего начать сразу работать и меньше кода писать для запросов?

Comment: База данных в данном случае совершенно не оправданно средство. Просто берите решение из boost, если подходит.

Comment: "std::map и понял, что из неё вытащить точки, попадающие в регион" - для этого std::map и не предназначен.

Comment: Сам использую 2. как самый приемлемый вариант по скорости.

Comment: И правда, а чем вам kd-tree не угодило? Реляционная база данных сразу делает всё на порядок сложнее (и если не повезёт, на два порядка медленнее). И не даёт алгоритмического выигрыша по сравнению со структурами в памяти.

Comment: На данном этапе сверху не могу оценить количество данных, в которых придётся копаться. Есть мысль, что однажды, всё же придётся по какой-то причине переезжать на СУБД, так зачем тянуть? А тут как раз момент, когда надо подключать стороннее решение. kd-tree - только индекс, хранение и сериализация данных на мне, а СУБД - всё вместе есть. В общем, прокрастинирую.

Answer (score 2):

Если выбирать вариант 3 то возможно пригодится функции работы с GeoPosition и GeoLocation. Они есть например в PostgreSQL и в его расширении http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ реализован более полный функционал